# Big number puzzle

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, algebra

I saw this on rec.puzzles many years ago, but can't find the reference to credit the source.

I am thinking of a large number.  If you want to multiply it by a two digit number $ab$ with $a \lt b$, search through the number for the digits $ba$ in order.  Write the part starting at $a$, two zeros, and the part ending with $b$, and you have the product.  If you represent the original number as $AbaB$ the product is $aB00Ab$.  If you want to multiply by $ab$ with $a \gt b$, let $c=a-1$ and look for $ac$.  If the number is $AacB$ the product is $cB00Aa$.  If you want to multiply it by a multiple of $11$, so $aa$, there are two copies of $aa$ in the number.  Do the same as in the previous sentence, but use the one that does not have a $9$ after it in the original number.

What number am I thinking of?

Comment: Wow, nice puzzle! Can we assume that the digits $ab$ for $a \neq b$ appear only once?

Comment: Do digits $b$ and $a$ have to be side by side in the big number? Does the "part starting at $a$" includes $a$? The same for $b$. Are there any restrictions as to what $a$ and $b$ can be?

Comment: Or am I getting this wrong and $ab$ is one specific number?

Comment: Is the essential equation $AbaB \times ab = aB00Ab$ where $A$ and $B$ are some strings of digits of unknown length?

Comment: @hexomino That's my interpretation.

Comment: @hexomino:  yes, that is correct

Comment: The answer I gave does not depend on the restriction you have on $a$ and $b$, and it still proves the impossibility of such a number. Indeed, you can see that the number found by @FlorianF has only one instance of $99$. By the way, just saying, it is not considered good practice to change your question when it already has a valid answer, in a way that invalidates this answer.

Comment: @OP: You wrote "multiplying by $ab$ with $a>b$" twice with different results. Is there a typo? Should we assume that the former should be $a<b$?

Comment: @NautilusThe first was supposed to be $a \lt b$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And here is the number you are probably thinking of:

> $(10^{108}-1)/109$ =
>  9174311926605504587155963302752293577981651376146788990825688073394495412844036697247706422018348623853211

It works only for $ab$ where $a \le b$.  I suppose that it is a mistake in the problem statement.  Others have proven that as it is, the problem is unsolvable.

And here is how I came to that number.

> This behaviour of the multiples being a rotation of the original number occurs when the number is the recurrent part of the decimal expansion of some 1/N.
>
>  For example for N=7, 1/N = 0.142857142857... .  The recurrent part is 142857.  The multiples of 142857 are 142857, 285714, 428571, 571428, 714285, 857142 and 999999.
>
>  The additional 00 indicate that 1/N actually starts with two zeroes: 0.009174...  The zeroes are stripped in the original number, but must be restored in every rotation of the number.  The fact that the recurrent part starts with 00 tells me that N is betwen 100 and 999.
>
>  The recurrent part of $1/N$ for a large N is of the form $(10^R-1)/N$ where R is the period of the decimal expansion, or the length of the recurrent part.  So I checked only numbers of that form.
>
>  The number of digits should have been 100 to accomodate with all the combinations of $ab$ once from 10 to 99, plus a second copy of $aa$'s from 11 to 99, plus 1 because the first and last digits can match only once.  The actual length is 106.  Since cases with $a<b$ are not counted, it actually could be anywhere from 46 and larger.  Anyway I tried all lengths up to 120.
>
>  So, using a computer, I searched for numbers of the form $(10^R-1)/N$ that contain all combination of 2 digits $ab$.  I didn't find any so I ignored the case $b=0$.  I found a few candidates.  But checking for which $ab$ the multiplication procedure actually works, I noticed that it works only when $a \le b$.  Since other have proven that the problem is not possible as stated, I assume it is a mistake, maybe the procedure for $a>b$ is different than for $a<b$.

PS: I have been playing with this problem.  You can extend it to $ab$ with $a > b$ with the following rule:

- if a = b+1 then search $bb9$ and split between the b's.
- if a > b+1 then search $b(a-1)$ and split between b and (a-1).

For example, to multiply by 42 don't search for 24 but 23 and split the number between 2 and 3.  For the search with 0's you might need to imagine the '00' in front.

Comment: `\geq` will produce $\geq$. Also, how did you come up with this number, and with "the" (?) way to fix the statement?

Comment: This does seem to be a very interesting number! It does seem that multiplying it by $ab$ with $a \geq b$ gives you some cyclic permutation of the digits with two 0s included but I don't see how it matches the question description. Could you expand a bit more, please?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I've googled around a bit and it looks like this is the periodic part of $\frac{1}{109}$ and is the 10th cyclic number (in decimal). This means that cyclic permutations of the number (including two 0s at the beginning) are multiples of it.

Comment: @hexomino I was doing the same :) it would still be interesting to see a natural way to come up with this number.

Comment: Multiplying by ab with a<b also gives a rotation of the number, it is only the method to find where to split the number that fails.

Comment: @FlorianF:  That was an oversight in my testing.  You are correct.  I have updated the question.  Your answer is correct as well.

Comment: In the mean time I have also been looking at the a<b case to see how to include it.

Comment: Extremely impressive!

Comment: Very nice, +1. It still doesn't exactly fit the question however (and in fact my answer still holds) as there is only one instance of 99 in this number.

Comment: True.  That's why I said "probably".  That is modulo a few oversights.  The correct rule would be _if_ there are 2 copies of 'aa' _then_ use the one that is not followed by a 9.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to prove that

> such a number cannot exist, because for any $a$ **there has to be more than one instance of $aa$ not followed by a $9$.**  The proof relies on the condition that for every digit $a$, there are exactly two instances of $aa$ in the number. Note that the number found by @FlorianF fails to meet this criterion (there is only one $99$).

Indeed

> **There is $999$ somewhere in $X$**, and no other $99$'s. Indeed, we know that there are only two $99$ sequences, and one of them is followed by a $9$.
>
>   Now let us multiply $X$ by $99$. Since there is $\color{red}{99}9$ in $X$, $99\times X$ ends with $\color{red}{99}$ and therefore **$X$ ends with $01$**. This is because the last two digits of $99\times x$ are always equal to $100$ minus the last two digits of $x$.
>
>   Now because of this, the product of $X$ by $aa$ for arbitrary $a$ ends with $aa$, and this gives us that for every digit $a$, the sequence $aa$ not followed by a $9$ has to be preceded by yet another $a$, which makes it $aaa(\text{some digit}\neq 9)$, which proves the claim.

---

Let me dump here previous thoughts that turned out not to be useful but might be in the future.

First,

> **$X$ ends with $1$.**
>  Indeed, by Rule #1 the product $X\times(ab)$ always ends with the digit $b$.

Second

> **$X$ begins with $9$** (followed either by a non-zero digit, or by $09$ and then a non-zero digit).
>  This is because $11\times X$ has two more digits than $X$. The smallest such number (with any fixed number of digits) is $909090...$ but there can't be more than one instance of $09$ in $X$, hence the precision in parentheses.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion as you by a different route. It seems something is probably wrong with the statement of the problem...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Indeed, if this is not the intended answer, since the OP does not have the original reference it will be hard to feel around for the correct statement.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Apologies my interpretation was that there be just one instance of $ab$ but I'll admit the wording seems to support your interpretation. Does this mean that, a priori, $X$ must contain every possible substring of two digits?

Comment: @hexomino Yes, that's how I interpret it.